# Setting timeout for NSInputStream and NSOutputStream

Tags: iphone, ios6

Can anyone please help setting a timeout for NSInputStream and NSOutputStream classes.

Comment: This should be helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687177/iphone-catching-a-connection-error-with-nsstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that apple doesn't support this. The answer is to create a timer, or, using threads when applicable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply donald but had implemented the same long back.